# How can I get rid of a file in my bare repo and my working repo?

Tags: git, bash

I have a bare repo and a working repo on my server.

I want to get rid of a file as it is causing me problems:

> error: Untracked working tree file
>   'web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php' would be overwritten by
>   merge.  Aborting

I it is in my .gitignore in my working directory and that is why it is un-tracked.

I'm trying to run a git pull from my bare repo.

Comment: a bare repo does not have a .gitignore ... so essentially I need this file purged from my bare repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file is already present in the to-be-merged branch.

this *branch* can also be the `upstream/master` (fetched from the bare repo), which you are trying to merge into your *local* `master` (in your working repo).

the very simple solution to the problem is:

- move your local file out of the way

  - `mv web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php.bak`
- merge your local branch with the upstream branch
- remove the offending file

  - `git rm web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php`
  - `git commit`
- push to upstream
- restore the file

  - `mv web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php.bak web/source/php/class.DBCredentials.php`
- let `.gitignore` do the rest.

Comment: I don't use multiple branches, so all my branches are master on their repo.  So how do I get rid of it.

Comment: How do I get rid of it on the "to-be-merged brach"

Comment: you cannot get rid of it, as it is the `master` branch from upstream. but see my updated answer.

Comment: very simple ... that is nuts!  I have access to the repo that bushed it to the server as well, just fyi.

Comment: just fyi, trying to insult me won't answer your question. afaict, my answer *answers* your question. if your question is about something else, then you should ask in a way that makes it clear what you want.